# Why my HttpRequest *always* trigger CDN?

Tags: c#, web, https

I use fiddler to simulate the brwoser's request.
In the browser, I can get what I want without any cookies, even in the new machine, new IP, it can success.
But When I use HttpRequest it always return cdn result, which is not what I expect, no exception. I haven't success even once.

https://www.yczy00.com/valid_code?t=0.034255412415&user_name=
This is the url, the random number can be changed and it doesn't matter.

This is what I did:

```
public static void InitializeEnvironment()
    {
        ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = int.MaxValue;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate (object sender, X509Certificate cert, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors error) { return true; };
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;//   ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
    }

private void Login(CookieContainer cc)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = null;
        try
        {
            request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://www.yczy00.com/valid_code?t={0}&user_name=", RealRandom.GetRandomDouble().ToString("f16")));
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0";
            request.Accept = "*/*";
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,zh-TW;q=0.7,zh-HK;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.3,en;q=0.2");
            request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br");
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Headers.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
            request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
            request.Referer = "https://www.yczy00.com/";
            request.CookieContainer = cc;
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "it can success" and "it always return CDN result"? What *exactly* do you expect to be returned, and what's *actually* returned?

Comment: What do you mean "returns CDN result"? What result are you expecting?

Comment: I excepct an image as return(Content-Type: image/jpeg), when it failed it return Content-Type: text/html @joh

Comment: @JohnWu                    1111111111111111

Comment: The behavior of the server is completely application-defined, so I can't advise you about that without a lot more specifics. The only tip I can give you is to follow basic problem isolation procedure by examining the Fiddler traces for any difference, however small.

Comment: @John Wu The only difference I can tell is in the https connection. However, I made breakpoint and try to make my behavior the same exactly browser it still doesn't work